# how to parse log with json object using fluentd

Tags: json, regex, parsing, fluentd

I have a nginx log file which has lines like the following:
`127.0.0.1 192.168.0.1 - [28/Feb/2013:12:00:00 +0900] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 777 "-" "Opera/12.0" - <{"key1":"value1","key2":98765,"key3":false,"key4":["one","two"],"key5":{"key22":98765,"key23":false,"key24":["one-one","two-two"]}}>`
As you can see the last value is a JSON object. Now I need to parse in the following format

```
1362020400 (28/Feb/2013:12:00:00 +0900)

record:
{
  "remote"              : "127.0.0.1",
  "host"                : "192.168.0.1",
  "user"                : "-",
  "method"              : "GET",
  "path"                : "/",
  "code"                : "200",
  "size"                : "777",
  "referer"             : "-",
  "agent"               : "Opera/12.0",
  "http_x_forwarded_for": "-",
  "myobject"            :{
                          "key1": "value1",
                          "key2": 98765,
                          "key3": false,
                          "key4": [
                            "one",
                            "two"
                          ],
                          "key5": {
                            "key22": 98765,
                            "key23": false,
                            "key24": [
                              "one-one",
                              "two-two"
                            ]
                          }
                         }
```

I can use the format like this:

```
expression /^(?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^\"]*?)(?: +\S*)?)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)"(?:\s+(?<http_x_forwarded_for>[^ ]+))?) \<(?<myobject>[^\>]*)\>?$/
time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
```

But that parse the last JSON object to a string. How to keep that value as a JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [filter/parser](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/parser) to parse from string to json object

```
<filter foo.bar>
  @type parser
  key_name myobject
  reserve_data true
  remove_key_name_field true
  hash_value_field parsed
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</filter>
```

This is the example

```
# input data:  {"host":"192.168.0.1", "myobject":"{\"key1\":1,\"key2\":2}"}
# output data: {"host":"192.168.0.1", "parsed":{"key1":1,"key2":2}}
```